# How to remove localstorage content without a specific key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `contenteditable` `div` that serves as an editor and allows users to input text and save it under a title. The title names are then appended to a separate div, with the id "Contentable", and when the user clicks on a title its contents (the text the user input) will show up inside the editor. I also added a button to remove any titles inside "Contentable", but I can't figure out how to remove them from the localstorage, as they don't have a specific key assigned to it. So far I was only able to remove the words from the div, not the actual localstorage.

```
    var editElem = document.getElementById("editor1");
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#savebtn").click(function() {
    var title = prompt("What would you like your title to be?");
    localStorage.setItem(title, editElem.innerHTML);
    titles = localStorage.getItem("titles");

    if (titles == null) {
      titles = [];
    } else {
      titles = JSON.parse(titles);
    }
    titles.push(title);
    localStorage.setItem("titles", JSON.stringify(titles));
    var htmlData = "<a onclick=showData('" + title + "')>" + title + "</a><br>";
    $("#Contentable").append(htmlData);
    var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;
    localStorage.setItem("userEdits", userVersion);
    editElem.innerHTML = "";
  });
});

function showData(txt) {
  editElem.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(txt);
}

function loadData()
{ 

  var htmlData=localStorage.getItem("titles");
  htmlData=htmlData.replace(/\[|\]/g, "");

  htmlData=htmlData.replace(/["']/g, "")
  htmlData=htmlData.split(",");

  var arlength=htmlData.length;
  console.log(arlength)
  for(num=0;num<arlength;num++)
  {

    $("#Contentable").append("<a onclick=showData('" + htmlData[num] + "')>" + htmlData[num] + "</a><br>");

  }

}
loadData();
var selected;
$("#Contentable a").click(function(){
  selected=$("#Contentable a").index(this);
  $("#Contentable a").removeClass("selected")
  $(this).addClass("selected");
})

$("a").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
});

$("#remove").click(function(){
  $("#Contentable a:eq("+selected+")").remove();
  //Code to remove from localstorage
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: Please provide some information on why this is the answer. Even though it might solve a problem, if you tell them WHY the problem is solved they might actually learn something.